# Unable to merge partitions using gParted in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to merge /dev/sda2 into /dev/sda6 and the remaining partitions in /dev/sda5.
I have tried to follow instructions on various forums but have been unsuccessful. I have deleted and re-created partition, used Ubuntu USB to boot and merge partitions from there. But no success.
Please help.
Please look at the following screenshots of gParted and fDisk:

[image: ScreenShot of gParted]

[image: ScreenShot of fDisk]

PS: I am not using dual-boot.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “the remaining partitions”?

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: `sda2` is primary and `sda6` is a part of extended partition. So you are goind to have a hard time merging them. Next time use GPT partition scheme instead of dos.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the size and amounts of data, it would be far easier and safer to merge the content of `sda6` into `sda2` than the other way around and then tell Ubuntu about the new location of `/home`.

1. Boot a live system since later you'll need to unmount `/home` and it would be much harder to operate Ubuntu without `/home`.
2. Mount `sda2`, `sda5`, and `sda6`. For simplicity's sake I'll assume their respective mount points are `/media/sda2`, `/media/sda5`, and `/media/sda6`.
3. Move all the content of `/media/sda2` into a single folder, say `sda2.orig`, to identify it more easily later. You can use a file manager or the following commands, whichever seems more convenient for you:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/sda2/sda2.orig
   sudo find /media/sda2 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name sda2.orig -exec mv -t /media/sda2/sda2.orig -- {} +
   ```
4. Copy `/media/sda6` (the mount point of `sda6`) to `/media/sda2` with the ”backup” option (`-a`) to restore the original owner, access rights and modification times of the files:

   ```
   shopt -s dotglob
   sudo cp -at /media/sda2 /media/sda6/*
   ```
5. Now we need to tell your Ubuntu installation about the new device for its `/home` mount point.

   1. Find the [UUID](//help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) of `/dev/sda2` with this command:

      ```
      sudo blkid /dev/sda2
      ```
   2. Open `/media/sda5/etc/fstab` for editing as super-user (`sudo nano`, `sudo vi`, `gksudo gedit`, or whatever editor you prefer) and find the line with `/home` in the 2nd column (helpfully titled “mount point” in a comment above).
   3. Replace the 1st column (“file system”) of that line with `UUID=` followed by the UUID found in step 5.1, e. g.:

      ```
      UUID=30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df  /home  ext4  ...
      ```
   4. Save the changes.
6. You can now reboot into your Ubuntu installation without further ado.

   If you get an error message saying that a file system could not be mounted, boot the live system again and verify the changes to `fstab` made in step 5. Include a copy of it in your question if you can't seem to find the mistake. `/media/sda5/var/log/boot.log` will also contain the boot error message.
7. Rearrange the original content of `sda2` (now in `/home/sda2.orig`) however you like.
8. Once you verified that everything is where it's supposed to be, you can delete `sda6`, move `sda5` and resize `sda2`. See [How to resize partitions?](/q/126153/175814) for more info on that. It may be wise to take your other partition resizing wishes into account before diving into this one.

I'm leaving this as a partial answer because I'm not sure what you mean by “the remaining partitions”. Once it becomes clear to me, I'll extend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backup any data on sda2 to a flash key or external disk. *(To restore later)*.

Backup any data on /home (sda6) to a flash key or external disk. *(For safety)*.

Boot a Ubuntu Live DVD. Start terminal, type `swapoff`. Quit terminal. Start gparted. Delete sda2. Move *(move by dragging the partition, or setting the numerical space in front of the partition)* sda1 all the way left. Resize *(resize by dragging the right handle)* sda1 as far to the right as you can. Move sda7 all the way right. Resize sda6 to the size you want, and then move it all the way right. Resize sda5 to the maximum available.

In terminal, type `swapon`. Reboot, and restore your backup from sda2 to your /home (sda6).

Done.

Cheers, Al